# google-cloud-monitoring python-API: metric without resource (Selecting a metric without a resource may have performance implications.)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I am following this [google-cloud-monitoring tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#monitoring_write_timeseries-python) on how to send data to Google Stackdriver using Python APIs. I just copy pasted the tutorial python snippet

```py
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3

import time

client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project = 'todag-239819'  
project_name = client.project_path(project)

series = monitoring_v3.types.TimeSeries()
series.metric.type = 'custom.googleapis.com/my_metric'
series.resource.type = 'gce_instance'
series.resource.labels['instance_id'] = '1234567890123456789'
series.resource.labels['zone'] = 'us-central1-f'
point = series.points.add()
point.value.double_value = 3.14
now = time.time()
point.interval.end_time.seconds = int(now)
point.interval.end_time.nanos = int(
    (now - point.interval.end_time.seconds) * 10**9)
client.create_time_series(project_name, [series])
print('Successfully wrote time series.')
```

I am able to execute the python code snippet locally succesfully

```sh
$ python stackdriver/example.py
Successfully wrote time series.
```

On Stackdriver tough **I see no data on the custom metric**, and I get the following warning `Selecting a metric without a resource may have performance implications.` (I waited for 30 mins to be sure it wasn't showing due of delays).

[image]

It looks like there is some problem registering the resource. I investigated a bit and found this looks like to be a common problem, based on [this in-code comment](https://github.com/yuriatgoogle/stackdriver-custom-metrics/blob/f039ac1add0c752e00a1fabfe379a97de9799272/app/routes.py#L23) on a python tutorial for Google Stackdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that to configure Stack Driver correctly you need to specify the `resource ID`. After some investigation the resource ID is the instance ID where your Google App Engine is running.

```
series.resource.labels['instance_id'] = '1234567890123456789'
```

You can find it in the GCP console, GAE -> INSTANCE.
Fixing this fixed my problem.